# c++ binary file io

Tags: c++, stl, io, binary-data

In trying to rework my logic in response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345853/protocol-buffers-issue-multiple-serializations-into-a-binary-file) question. I have decided to serialize protocol buffer objects using `message-size` + `protobuf-object-after-SerializeToArray` pairs,(don't worry if you don't get what I am talking about). Anyhow my implementation doesn't work. So I decided to see how c++ fstream works. It's a semantic nightmare, I can't be sure if I need to use `seekg` to reposition the position handle after each read (or perhaps even after each write). I am only using write() and get() methods. The following contrived program is failing, why is it failing, and would I need seekg in this context ?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void write()
{
  boost::uint8_t one = (boost::uint32_t )255;
  boost::uint8_t two = (boost::uint32_t) 254;
  boost::uint8_t three =(boost::uint32_t) 253;

  std::fstream file("test", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::trunc);

  file.write( (char *) &one, sizeof(one));
  file.write( (char *) &two, sizeof(two));
  file.write( (char *) &three, sizeof(two));

  std::cout << file.tellg() << std::endl;
  file.flush();
  file.close();
}

void read()
{
  boost::uint8_t one=0;
  boost::uint8_t two=0;
  boost::uint8_t three=0;

  std::fstream file("test", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::binary);


  file.get((char *) & one, sizeof(one)); 
  file.get((char *) & two, sizeof(two)); 
  file.get((char *) & three, sizeof(three)); 

  std::cout << file.tellg() << std::endl;

  std::cout << (boost::uint32_t) one << ":" << (boost::uint32_t) two  << ":" << (boost::uint32_t)three<< std::endl;
  file.close();
}


int main()
{
  write();
  read();  
}
```

The output is:

```
3
-1
0:0:0
```

C++ binary file io is making me feel sad and foolish :(

Comment: `boost::uint8_t` is `unsigned char`. To output the value on `std::cout`, you should cast it to `int` (or any other non-char integer type).

Comment: Yeah I just figured that out as well, thanks, updated the question.

Comment: Hexdumping the resulting file gives me `feff 00fd` (keep in mind endianess :), so the writing part seems to be working, at least.

Comment: Use a debugger instead of relying on `cout`, and check `fstream` state after all usages in the `read` code.

Comment: @steve The debugger reasons about things in memory, not things on file, or logical usage issues of libraries ? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of [istream::get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/), you should use [istream::read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/).

The former extracts characters until either (n - 1) characters have been extracted or the delimiting character is found. The later just reads unformated data from file.

Answer (score 2):

`fstream::get()` is tailored towards text. It expects the size parameter to account for a trailing nul in the buffer. Pass `sizeof(one) + 1` as the size. It will also stop reading on a `'\n'`. You can change what character is considered the delimiter, but it doesn't seem you can use "no delimiter, please". If you want raw binary data, use `fstream::read()`.

When reading single bytes, you can also use

```
one = (boost::uint8_t) file.get();
two = (boost::uint8_t) file.get();
three = (boost::uint8_t) file.get();
```

But that is naturally no good for data of size > 1. You'll need `fstream::read()` for those.

```
file.read((char *) & one, sizeof(one));
file.read((char *) & two, sizeof(two));
file.read((char *) & three, sizeof(three));
```

Result:

```
3
3
255:254:253
```

Comment: Jeesus christ, back to ansi-c for file IO I guess :/, this is a minefield. Problem is I got to write in the protocol buffer binary string and the prepend the size in as binary. I remember the ability to alter the behaviour of cout to print integers as hex and such, is there a way to get the fstream to behave dumber ? (i.e., no tokenizing of any sort) ?

Comment: Nono, I don't know the c++ standard library well enough, always using QT :P Use `fstream::read()`, like J. Calleja says.

Comment: but that causes some tokenization to happen in the stdlib/stl code :(, I'm preprocessing a text-file into a binary format to get away from text processing :D

Comment: No, `fstream::read()` does no tokenization. `fstream::get()` does.

Comment: thanks for the perseverance :D celt got it right first tho, and he is new, so I will give him the tick :D

Comment: J. Calleja got it first, to be embarresingly correct about it. But I understand why you didn't get it from his answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I am using a smartphone.  It is not easy to type.

Answer (score 1):

`istream::get` is not meant for binary I/O, but for textual I/O. Especially, `file.get(ptr, n)` reads a C string, i.e. reads only n-1 characters max, and then null-terminates. Moreover, reading will stop if you ever encounter a `'\n'` in your stream (not what you want in binary I/O). Note that if you were checking the stream state (always a good idea when doing I/O), you'd find that the first read attempt already resulted in an error.

You should instead use `read` and `write` for binary I/O (or alternatively, work with the corresponding stream buffers directly).